# How do I delete lines of a given interval in a file containing a matching word?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I need to use sed to delete from a file only the lines containing a given word. But if my file has 50 lines, I only need to look at the first 30 lines for example.

I know that:

```
sed '1,30d' f.txt
```

will delete the first 30 lines of the file.

And:

```
sed '/Text/d' f.txt
```

will delete all the lines in the file containing the matching word "Text".

How do I combine these two to solve my problem? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you want to delete the lines containing `Text` within the first 30 lines in your file.

You can say:

```
sed '1,30{/Text/d}' f.txt
```

---

If you wanted to delete the first 30 lines **and** the lines containing `Text` anywhere in the file, you could say:

```
sed '1,30d;/Text/d' f.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You miss "-i" option:

```
sed -i '1,30{/Text/d}' f.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed "/Text/ d;30 q" f.txt
```

should be faster, especially on huge file **IF** you discard line after 30. If not  previous solution are the best